# Why should anyone wait for the official release of pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there any benefits to waiting for the official release in the country of the user?

Like more Pokestops, or Pokemon spawning rate.

(I'm asking because i live in Abu Dhabi and the number of pokestops is unbelievably low inside the heart of the city)

Comment: Users voting to close this as "Opinion-based": I don't think this question is asking for opinions, but rather, *facts*.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about India (where I live), majority of the area is geoblocked leaving a few metro cities open to play the game.

So, Niantic's been taking strict action against those who don't abide by their rules.

About benefits, actually there are none (or "not having your account deleted" is surely a benefit), but still, if you play before the official release, most of the people around you are likely to treat you as a cheater (those who aren't well acquainted with the APKs outside of Play Store's world).

Also, after the official release of the game in your country, the **Pokemon GO Environment** is going to be a better one.

Comment: Wouldn't not having your account deleted be a benefit?

Comment: Haha! You nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious problem of it's against Niantic's rules to download and play through 3rd party sources, and you might have your account banned. There is also a strong social aspect to the game and it would greatly take away from the experience if everywhere you go you're the only person playing.

Meaning no one would be at any pokéstops, no one placing lures, and no one fighting for gyms. This could also lead to an issue of you being higher level before others and there's a chance you'd be reported as cheating.